# What is the role of "function(v)"?

Tags: r

There is a line which calculates lower confidence interval for each group and it goes like this:

```
lower <- tapply(airquality$Temp, airquality$Month, function(v) t.test(v)$conf.int[1])
```

What is the role of `function(v)` in the line?

Comment: Create a function which takes `v` as input?

Comment: Just add `{` and `}` to make it clearer: `lower <- tapply(airquality$Temp, airquality$Month, function(v) { t.test(v)$conf.int[1] })`. What you are defining is an _anonymous_ function to use with `tapply`

Comment: `tapply` requires you to supply a single function, e.g. `mean` or `sum`. In your case, `t.test` would work except that you want to take the first part of the confidence interval. So, with `function()` you create a temporary function on the fly (i.e. an anonymous function), like @rbm explains.

Comment: Oh I get it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`tapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) documentation:

*Apply a function to each cell of a ragged array, that is to each (non-empty) group of values given by a unique combination of the levels of certain factors.*

The `function(v)` is the function which is applied to each cell of that particular ragged array.

Its syntactical necessary because `tapply` can't apply a `t.test` directly like in your example. So you define a function with a single argument `v` which comes from `tapply`during execution.

Answer (score 2):

It is to create an anonymous function.
You can check out this page to learn more about anonymous functions.
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions

You can rephrase code in this way:

```
myConf <- function(v) {
    return(t.test(v)$conf.int[1])
}
lower <- tapply(airquality$Temp, airquality$Month, myConf)
```

You can create a function `myConf` and use it as the `FUN` argument for the `tapply`.
You now should be aware of that

```
function(v) return(t.test(v)$conf.int[1])
```

create a function which takes an input `v` and return output `t.test(v)$conf.int[1]`.

Comment: *It is just people are too lazy to think of a name for the function.* Who are you to say this?

Comment: Okay. I know there is a great philosophy behind "anonymous function". [wiki Anonymous Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) But you should not deny that too lazy to think of a name for a one-time function is a common reason to use an anonymous function in R. And it also explain the name "Anonymous".

Comment: I think the correct term is efficient